# Reactstrap InputGroup resposive Issue in mobile view

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, reactstrap

I'm using `InputGroup` component from `reactstrap` inside a modal. In Desktop view it looks fine but Mobile view Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
 <Row>
      <Col xs='2'>
                <span>Price(s)</span>
      </Col>
      <Col xs='10'>
           <PriceInput
             cats={this.state.cats}
           />
       </Col>
 </Row>
```

price input and description fields are add as another component , so i can add more than one price to it

`PriceInput` Code

```
  <Row>
       <Col xs='3'>
             <InputGroup 
               className={'form-group'}>
               <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">{props.symbol} 
               </InputGroupAddon>
               <Input
                   type="text"
                   placeholder='0.00'/>
             </InputGroup>

         </Col>
         <Col xs='7'>
           <Input
            type="text"
            placeholder='description'/>
          </Col>
          <Col xs='2'>
            <Button >
             <i color={'red'} 
               className='zmdi zmdi-delete'>
             </i>
            </Button>
           </Col>
     </Row>
```

How can i set Price and Price symbol wrap together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your `xs`  props to `xl` it will work